# Which framework to use for creating mobile apps?

Tags: ruby, cordova, mobile, rhodes

I want to develop a mobile app (it is desire not to be browser based app), but also to have a website with same information, same database, images, etc... I would like to create one application and that both web and mobile uses that application to get/post data.

I found several proposals:

1) Phonegap;

2) Ruby (Rhodes FW);

3) Zend IDE 10 (Zend cloud + Phonegap).

Which of these solutions is the best for me?!

Comment: May want to re-read http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask. Also, check out http://www.icenium.com/.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of application you are making. If it needs to have serious integrations with the OS, Phonegap should not be your first choice. I have seen plenty of tries to make Phonegap work with complex applications, but there is just no comparing with the Native OS'es.

That being said, I think you have mixed up a couple of things.

What you need, is some sort of an api, to which both the mobile applications and the website will connect to. Lets call it a backend. The most common way to do this nowadays is with REST. And for rest, with PHP, there are plenty of options out there. But I would name Zend Framework 2 and Slims as really solid contenders in this area. As far as Ruby, I can't say, haven't made any API's using Ruby

Comment: As I understood, Rhodes will compile as native. Is it possible to develop an app with Rhodes, which will be compiled as native app, and also same code could be used as a base for web (just to change layouts in that case)? (is it possible?! this is I was interested in, but obviously was not clear enough.. not REST services..)